# How to use UIkit with Vue?

Tags: vue.js, uikit

I installed uikit with yarn.

```
yarn add uikit
```

And additionally `less-loader`, `less` and `css-loader` because [this site](https://aravindvoggu.in/using-uikit-with-vuejs-14e16d124f6c) said so.
Now I tried using UIkit in my App.vue like so.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="uk-alert-primary" uk-alert>
        <a class="uk-alert-close" uk-close></a>
        <p>This is a text!</p>
    </div>

    <table class="uk-table uk-table-striped">
      <tr><td>Hello World!</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Hello World!</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Hello World!</td></tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import UIkit from 'uikit';
import Icons from 'uikit/dist/js/uikit-icons';
UIkit.use(Icons);

export default {
  mounted: function() {
    this.getTestJson();
  },
  methods: {
    getTestJson: function() {
      this.$http.get('http://localhost:8090/test').then((res) => {
        console.log(res.body)
      });
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

This is not enough, the UIkit components are not displayed properly. What else do I have to do?

[image: fail]

Do I have to use [vuikit](https://vuikit.js.org/)?

Comment: Did you follow the blogpost advices also about the UIKit theming? It seems to me you did not introduce any UIKit theme in the sourcecode above.

Answer (score 2):

This [link](https://aravindvoggu.in/uikit-with-vuejs-vue-cli-3-db811e43c46b/) will help, and basically you need to do the following:

- After installing uikit package, add this code to App.vue

```html
<style lang="less">
  @import "../node_modules/uikit/src/less/uikit.less";
</style>
```

- And then add this code to main.js

```js
import uk from 'uikit'
import Icons from 'uikit/dist/js/uikit-icons'
uk.use(Icons)
```

- You can also add global mixin for **uk** object in case you wanted to use UIKit JavaScript functionality anywhere in your components e.g. `this.uk.toggle('#toggle-elm').toggle()`:

```js
Vue.mixin({
  data: function () {
    return {
      get uk () {
        return uk
      }
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    ...
```

Comment: Link does not work anymore. Any alternative tutorials?